# C# & SQL Server - insert into different tables (if/case statement)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert-into

I have list of SYMBOLS and their data that are being inserted into `MYTABLE`. I would like that if `SYMBOL = 'ABC'`, the data will be inserted into `MYTABLE_ABC`, if `SYMBOL = 'DCE'` it will inserted into `MYTABLE_DCE` etc...

I am using SQL Server. Thinking about IF/CASE statement? But can't figure out the syntax in C# console app.

```
Public String toInsert()
{
    String output = "insert into MYTABLE (id,symbol,date,time, value,type) values ( " + id + ",'" + symbol + "', ('" + date +"'), ('" + time + "')," + value + ",'" + type + "')";
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Insert obligatory "Don't use string concatenation to generate SQL statements" comment here.

Comment: You can 86 the "String output" and just do a "return "insert ...."
Then again, why not just assign that inline, rather than making a method out of it?

Comment: @SixtySeven you need to use parameterized query in your case it will be more manageable and readability will also be better.. also if you are wanting to do conditional insert based on `ABC || DCE` then you need to rethink your Insert method

Comment: Why do you have two tables with the same schema? `symbol` is already a column in your example, just insert or query on that column instead of using two tables.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I don't it is too likely that a user who has rep of 1 and just created their account today can appreciate the meaning of your comment (of course I know what you're referring to).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about...

```
public String toInsert()
{
  if (symbol == "ABC")
    return "insert into MYTABLE_ABC (id,symbol,date,time, value,type) values ( " + id + ",'" + symbol + "', ('" + date +"'), ('" + time + "')," + value + ",'" + type + "')";
  else
  if (symbol == "DEF")
    return "insert into MYTABLE_DEF (id,symbol,date,time, value,type) values ( " + id + ",'" + symbol + "', ('" + date +"'), ('" + time + "')," + value + ",'" + type + "')";
  else
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can even simplify it by using a temporary variable for the table name like you have done with id, date, time, ... then you need to write the query only once

Comment: this is almost correct, if you the OP is wanting to know if the INSERT succeeded then the method should return a bool not a string also why return the insert statement when you as well as the OP never show where the query is being executed ..

Comment: @MethodMan i simply answered the question :)

Comment: with more experience you would know that it's not good to use concatenation when build a query string

Comment: @MethodMan that's your opinion and i respect that but an answer like "don't use concatenation" does not help the original poster at all.

Comment: yes it does especially when I mentioned to use parameterized queries very low quality in my opinion

Comment: @MethodMan Your comments on the answers to this question sound kind of negative to me. You don't like any answers given to this question, yet you have not provided an answer of your own and describe the benefits of using a parameterized query. Someone has also down-voted all the answers, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was you. It would really be more constructive if you spent the time to give your answer to this question.

Comment: Adam  I am using your example/code logic - helped me alot - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

why not just write the table name as a variable? You can do to the string whatever you like, because it is a string, not a function or something else.

Like:

```
String Table_Name;
switch (symbol)
{
    case "ABC": Table_Name = "MYTABLE_ABC";
    case "DEF": Table_Name = "MYTABLE_DEF";
(blabla....)
}
String output = "insert into " +Table_Name+ " (id,symbol,date,time, value,type) values ( " + id + ",'" + symbol + "', ('" + date +"'), ('" + time + "')," + value + ",'" + type + "')";

            return output;
```

Comment: good example but I would recommend to the OP that they should build query using parameters also would make for better readability and prevent against any potential `Sql Injection`

Comment: Jianing Li Great solution!  @MethodMan tnx for your points,  though it would be much more helpful if you could write an example/structure of how would you wrote it using parameters instead ,-)

Answer (score -1):

Use the [String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method and to do the string concatenations.

You could just append the value `symbol` to `"MYTABLE_"` when creating the insert statement string. If every value of `symbol` follows the same pattern then that will work. If you want more flexibility to identify unknown symbol values or to format the table name differently depending on the value of `symbol`, then using a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement might be the way to go.

```
public String toInsert()
{
    String output = String.Format("insert into MYTABLE_{0} (id,symbol,date,time, value,type) values ( '{1}', ('{2}'), ('{3}'), {4}, '{5}', {6} )", symbol, id, symbol, date, time, value, type);

    return output;
}

public String toInsert()
{
    String tableName;

    switch (symbol)
    {
        case "ABC":
        case "XYZ":
        case "B2M":
            tableName="MYTABLE_" + symbol;
            break;
        case "A12":
            tableName="MYTABLE_TEST";
            break;
        case string.Empty:
        case NULL:
            tableName="MYTABLE";
            break;
        default:
            // as an example the default case could throw an error if you don't want to process unknown symbols. Or you could use a different tableName format pattern
            // throw new Exception("Unknown value of symbol variable ({0}", symbol);
            tableName = "MYTABLE_UnknownSymbol_"+symbol;
            break;
    }

    String output = String.Format("insert into {0} (id,symbol,date,time, value,type) values ( '{1}', ('{2}'), ('{3}'), {4}, '{5}', {6} )", myTableName, id, symbol, date, time, value, type);

    return output;
}
```